# ASP.NET C# Parameterized Query Returning Nothing

Tags: asp.net, sql, parameterized

Okay I am a noob to parameterized queries. I understand why you should use them and all but I cannot find any resource that shows the correct way or at least one that shows the correct way that actually works.

So my question is about whether or not my code is right. It compiles and runs just fine but it returns absolutely nothing in the gridview.

```
 protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchBoxValue = SearchBox.Text;
    string columnNameValue = ColumnName.SelectedValue;
    columnNameValue.ToLower();

    SqlCommand searchCommand = new SqlCommand();
    searchCommand.Connection = connection;
    searchCommand.CommandText = "select firstname AS FirstName,lastname AS LastName, zipcode as ZipCode, phone AS Phone, email AS Email, cancersurvivor AS CancerSurvivor, ethnicity AS Ethnicity from registrants where @columnname = @searchterm";

    SqlParameter columnParam = new SqlParameter();
    columnParam.ParameterName = "@columnname";
    columnParam.Value = columnNameValue;

    SqlParameter searchBoxParam = new SqlParameter();
    searchBoxParam.ParameterName = "@searchterm";
    searchBoxParam.Value = searchBoxValue;

    searchCommand.Parameters.Add(columnParam);
    searchCommand.Parameters.Add(searchBoxParam);

    UpdateTable(searchCommand);

}
```

The UpdateTable function takes in the an SqlCommand object and then uses a DataAdapter object to execute the command and fills a DataTable object then sets the gridview datasource to the datatable object and binds it.

Like I said before I am really looking for the proper way to do this? do I need a stored procedure in order to do this? I am confused by all this and why it is not working.

Comment: In your query you have `WHERE @parameter = @parameter` is this intentiional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot parameterise `@columnname`. This needs to be a literal in your query.

Your statement

```
select 
 /* .... */
from registrants where @columnname = @searchterm
```

will return all rows from `registrants` if the value of the parameters happens to be the same or no rows otherwise.

It will not look and see if you have a column of that name and see if `@searchterm` exists in it.

To do this in a safe way you would need to check that `columnNameValue` matches one of a whitelist of valid column names (as you must know the possible column names in that table) and concatenate it into your query. **Do not concatenate unvalidated user input.** as then you open yourself up to SQL injection.

So you might implement it something like

```
using System.Linq;

protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string columnNameValue = ColumnName.SelectedValue.ToLower();

    var validColumnNames = new string[] { "firstname", "lastname", "zipcode" };

    if (!validColumnNames.Contains(columnNameValue))
    {
        throw new Exception("Unexpected column name " + columnNameValue);
    }

    /* ... code omitted */

    searchCommand.CommandText = "select firstname AS FirstName,lastname AS LastName, zipcode as ZipCode, phone AS Phone, email AS Email, cancersurvivor AS CancerSurvivor, ethnicity AS Ethnicity from registrants where " + columnNameValue + " = @searchterm";

    /* ... code omitted */
}
```

Comment: I see what your saying. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of paramtrized command are to prevent sql injection. You cannot parametrize the name of the column, sql will take it as a string.

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchBoxValue = SearchBox.Text;
    string columnNameValue = ColumnName.SelectedValue;
    columnNameValue.ToLower();

    SqlCommand searchCommand = new SqlCommand();
    searchCommand.Connection = connection;
    //Put the column name directly in the request, but use a parameter for the search value
    searchCommand.CommandText = "select firstname AS FirstName,lastname AS LastName, zipcode as ZipCode, phone AS Phone, email AS Email, cancersurvivor AS CancerSurvivor, ethnicity AS Ethnicity from registrants where " + columnNameValue  + " = @searchterm";

    /* No need for this part
    SqlParameter columnParam = new SqlParameter();
    columnParam.ParameterName = "@columnname";
    columnParam.Value = columnNameValue;
    */

    SqlParameter searchBoxParam = new SqlParameter();
    searchBoxParam.ParameterName = "@searchterm";
    searchBoxParam.Value = searchBoxValue;

    //searchCommand.Parameters.Add(columnParam);
    searchCommand.Parameters.Add(searchBoxParam);

    UpdateTable(searchCommand);

}
```

Comment: I actually used your code. Works great and I understand why. Thanks

Comment: @stewbydoo - Hopefully you implemented some sort of validation. I've added a quick example to my answer of this.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in how you're trying to make your column name as a parameter.  You'll want to change the query as a whole to reflect which column you want to filter by.  Try the following:

```
protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchBoxValue = SearchBox.Text;
    string columnNameValue = ColumnName.SelectedValue;
    columnNameValue.ToLower();

    SqlCommand searchCommand = new SqlCommand();
    searchCommand.Connection = connection;
    searchCommand.CommandText = String.Format("select firstname AS FirstName,lastname AS LastName, zipcode as ZipCode, phone AS Phone, email AS Email, cancersurvivor AS CancerSurvivor, ethnicity AS Ethnicity from registrants where {0} = @searchterm",columnNameValue);

    SqlParameter searchBoxParam = new SqlParameter();
    searchBoxParam.ParameterName = "@searchterm";
    searchBoxParam.Value = searchBoxValue;

    searchCommand.Parameters.Add(columnParam);
    searchCommand.Parameters.Add(searchBoxParam);

    UpdateTable(searchCommand);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to work, you'd have to build the SQL statment dynamically and execute with sp_executesql inside the proc as so:

```
DECLARE @IntVariable int;
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

/* Build the SQL string one time.*/
SET @SQLString =
     N'SELECT BusinessEntityID, NationalIDNumber, JobTitle, LoginID
       FROM AdventureWorks2012.HumanResources.Employee 
       WHERE BusinessEntityID = @BusinessEntityID';
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@BusinessEntityID tinyint';
/* Execute the string with the first parameter value. */
SET @IntVariable = 197;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
                      @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;
/* Execute the same string with the second parameter value. */
SET @IntVariable = 109;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition,
                      @BusinessEntityID = @IntVariable;
```

You still have the benefit of using parametrized queries and not exposing yourself to SQL Injection.

Source [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).
Another **very useful** link [is this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/01/04/dynamic-sql-sql-injection.aspx).